# Centered content is cut out of parent with fixed height and scrollbar

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I have a **parent with overflow-y and a fixed height**. I wish to **center align its child**. The content of the **child can vary in size**, and sometimes it **overflows the parent** and triggers a scrollbar. In those cases, the top and bottom **content of the child is cut out**.

**I wish the child to be center aligned**, but only if it's smaller than the parent. Or it could always be center aligned, but then the **content shouldn't be cut out**.

Check out the problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/gumy023z/

```css
.parent {
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  
  /* Comment out the flex, and all the content will be available */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    This is a test <br> This is a test <br> This is a test
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *alignment* will work in the *flex axis* of a *flexbox*. So you can switch to a *column flexbox* and give `min-height: 0` (which *overrides* the default `min-width: auto` setting for a *flex item*) for the `child` element - see demo below:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: red;
  height: 40px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* ADDED */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.child {
  min-height: 0; /* ADDED */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    1. This is a test <br> 2. This is a test <br> 3. This is a test
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks! I've bumped into another problem though, while implementing your solution: I can't add padding-bottom to the child - it wont work. Any idea why?

Comment: Thanks, but that actually pushes the top content outside of the parent. Any idea why?

Comment: Any other solution to get the desired effect?

Comment: Im not able to make it work with `padding` though :(

Comment: Welcome to 2019 :D